# Curl -u equivalent in HTTP request

Tags: http, curl

I've been trying to plug into the Toggl API for a project, and their examples are all using CURL. I'm trying to use the C# wrapper which causes a bad request when trying to create a report, so I thought I'd use Postman to try a simple HTTP request.

I can't seem to get the HTTP request to accept my API Token though. Here's the example that they give (CURL):

```
curl -u my-secret-toggl-api-token:api_token -X GET "https://www.toggl.com/reports/api/v2/project/?page=1&user_agent=devteam@example.com&workspace_id=1&project_id=2"
```

I've tried the following HTTP request with Postman with a header called
api_token with my token as the value:

```
https://www.toggl.com/reports/api/v2/project/?user_agent=MYEMAIL@EMAIL.COM&project_id=9001&workspace_id=9001
```

(changed ids and email of course).

Any help on how to use the CURL -u in HTTP would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Well, in Postman, select Basic Auth, fill Username with my-secret-toggl-api-token, and Password with api_token. Refresh headers and there you go

Comment: I did this and I believe it's worked! I now get a different error but I think that's down to my permissions in our Toggl Team, thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The easy way is adding credential into url as `user:pass@` format.

```
https://my-secret-toggl-api-token:api_token@www.toggl.com/reports/api/v2/project/?page=...
        <---------------------------------->
```

Alternately you can use credential with your http header like below:

```
Authorization: Basic XXXXXX
```

Here `XXXXXX` is `base64(my-secret-toggl-api-token:api_token)`

Comment: I used the Basic Authorization in Postman and it returns a different error for me, which I now believe is related to my access within Toggl. Thank you for the answer, it helped a lot!

Comment: Probably worth noting here that the `:api_token` part of this is the exact string required, e.g. `https://aaa111...bbb222:api_token@www.toggl.com/...`

Answer (score 0):

As explained to me in another post, you can pass the api token to the user property if you are using HttpWebRequest:

```
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"my-secret-toggl-api-token:api_token")));
```

Answer (score 0):

### Using [fetch](https://github.com/lquixada/cross-fetch)

In `node` environment, your request might look something like so:

```
const url = 'https://www.toggl.com/reports/api/v2/project/page=1&user_agent=devteam@example.com&workspace_id=1&project_id=2';
const token = 'my-secret-toggl-api-token:api_token';

fetch(url, {
  method: 'GET', // not required
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Basic ${Buffer.from(String(token)).toString('base64')}`,
  },
})
```