# curl commander username password contain character '@'

Tags: http, curl, http-headers

I have a requests query need to addition the credential.

The apis from this production:

https://www.riskiq.com/products/passivetotal/

According to the page [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34637034/curl-u-equivalent-in-http-request)

I can use the user:pass@ format to api address
https://api.passivetotal.org/v2/dns/passive/unique/

but my user String is myname@email.com

how to do this format?

On this address, it also said Alternately you can use credential with your http header like below:

```
Authorization: Basic XXXXXX
```

I put:

```
Authorization: Basic  base64(myname@email.com.au:keystring)
```

in http head, but it do not working. It still give me 405 error

```
status: 405
{
   "message": "The method is not allowed for the requested URL."
}
```

what is the correct way to writing http head like this.

only curl -u command works.

ps: any way to see the raw request of curl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to base64-encode "username:password". See https://www.greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7617.html#rfc.section.2.

Comment: I use Authorization: Basic base64(myname@email.com.au:keystring), but still get error.

Comment: You need to put the *result* of base64-encoding into the field value.

Comment: into the field value where?