# How do I set the user property "-u" for an HttpWebRequest request

Tags: c#, .net, httpwebrequest, api-key

I can't figure out how to set the -u / --user property of the HttpWebRequest request. My goal here is to set the --user to an api key I have, similar to the command

```
curl https://api.stripe.com/v1/customers?limit=3 -u api_key***************:
```

I have tried setting the UserAgent propety instead, but it doesn't work:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(endpoint);
request.UserAgent = "api_key***************:";
```

I am trying to get a JSON response from a web API that requires an API key in the -u part. Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: not sure how -u works, but from the example, you might need to add a header `request.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer YOUR_SECRET_KEY";` which might solve it.

Comment: No luck with this one but thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34637034/curl-u-equivalent-in-http-request possible duplicated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + Convert.ToBase64String(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes($"api_key***************:")));
```

Apparently you use the -u or -user command in curl to use Basic authentication. It's strange to me that there is an api key in the username field but since there is a colon in your example that is probably what the API expects.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, totally thought it would work as the curl command does. But unfortunately I'm still getting a 401 'Unauthorized' error. again the curl command is working with the exact same password. So strange to me

Comment: I made a change to the answer, the "Basic " part was in the key parameter where the value "Authorization" should have been.